# Wieso ist Fußball so "pomadig"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, etymology

Es ist EM-Zeit (Stand: Juni 2016), viele Fußballspiele, die ich mit Vergnügen sehe.
Ein neues Wort habe ich gelernt: pomadig. Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/pomadig) bedeutet es "träge" oder "schwerfällig".

Ich habe dieses Wort allerdings noch nie in irgendeiner anderen Sportart (oder überhaupt anderswo) gehört. Hat das einen bestimmten Grund, bezogen auf die Herkunft des Worts, o.Ä.?

Comment: Was genau ist deine Frage? Warum sie zum Wort "pomadig" gegriffen haben und nicht zu einem Begriff wie "langweilig" (was die EM ja angeblich sein soll). Wenn das deine Frage ist, dann kann man die Frage nicht beantworten, und sie ist "primarily opinion-based". Falls deine Frage etwas anderes ist, kannst das bitte klarstellen.

Comment: @Em1 [Der Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30465/wieso-ist-fu%c3%9fball-so-pomadig/30469#comment74430_30469) erklärt es schön. Meine Frage ist, warum man im Fußball so unglaublich viel (suche bei Google nach "pomadig" und Du kriegst **nur** Fußball-Ergebnisse) von "pomadig" spricht, während das in anderen Sportarten nicht so ist.

Comment: @Downvoter Wenn Du nach "pomadig Handball/Eishockey/Basketball" googelst, bekommst Du Treffer für die einzelnen Sportarten. Fußball ist halt viel populärer, deshalb wird da auch mehr berichtet, und entsprechend gibt es mehr Google-Treffer. Der Begriff läßt sich mMn zumindest auf alle Spiel-Sportarten gleichermaßen anwenden.

Comment: Es gibt in deutschen Berichterstattung die Stilregel, dass man Ausdrücke oder Redewendungen nicht ständig wiederholen soll. Da über Fußball allerdings sehr viel berichtet wird und dabei immer wieder die gleichen Dinge zu beschreiben sind, benötigen die Kommentatoren eine große Anzahl von Synonymen für häufige Begriffe, z. B. für _langsam: bedächtig, behäbig, gemächlich, schleppend, schwerfällig, träge, lahm, schlafmützig, in aller Ruhe, ohne Eile, im Schneckentempo_ oder eben auch mal _pomadig._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Pomade ist ein Fett, das man in der Parfumherstellung und auch zur Körperpflege benutzt. Es hat ungefähr die Konsistenz von Schweineschmalz, riecht aber anders und wird auch aus anderen Ausgangsstoffen hergestellt.

Im Bereich der Körperpflege gibt es Lippenpomade, die heute fast zur Gänze von Lippenpflegestiften verdrängt wurde, und es gibt die Haarpomade, die man sich wie ein Haargel in die Haare schmiert.

Anfangs (19. Jahrhundert) wurde diese Haarpomade gerne von adeligen Männern zur Frisurgestaltung benutzt, zu einer Zeit als die Perücken bereits aus der Mode gekommen waren. Zu Beginn des 20. Jahrhunderts wurde es aber auch generell in der Männerwelt Mode, sich das Zeug in die Haare zu schmieren. Jeder Mann, der es sich leisten konnten, und der Wert auf gepflegtes Aussehen legte, benutze Pomade um sein Haupthaar möglichst flach an die Kopfhaut zu kleben.

Vereinzelt hielt sich diese Mode über die 1950er (Elvis Presley) bis in die 1980er (Falco). In den 1970er Jahren gab es sogar einen Musik-Film mit John Travolta, in dem die Pomade (bzw. deren englische Bezeichnung) als Titel des Films verwendet wurde: Grease.

Wer sich Pomade in die Haare gab wollte oftmals als mehr gelten als er war, und so war die Pomade unter anderem auch in Unterweltkreisen sehr beliebt. Man kann ohne große Mengen Pomade keinen Mafia-Film drehen.

Aus diesem Unterwelt-Umfeld hat das von der Pomade abgeleitete Adjektiv »pomadig« seine erste Bedeutung: anmaßend; als mehr gelten wollen als man ist. Vielleicht auch: blasiert. Wobei hier eher die Adeligen, die diese Mode überhaupt erste einführten, die Paten des Wortes waren.

Nun ist es aber auch so, dass jemand, der sich anmaßend und blasiert benimmt, selten hektische oder schnelle Bewegungen vollführt. Im Gegenteil: Man versucht zu zeigen, dass man von nichts beeindruckt wird, und das erreicht man durch langsames Sprechen und durch langsame Bewegungen. Und da kommt die zweite Bedeutung von *pomadig* her: Träge, ohne Emotionen, sich einer schwerfälligen Körpersprache bedienend.

---

Mit Fußball oder anderen Sportarten hat das freilich genau gar nichts zu tun.

Ein Sportkommentator wird vermutlich einen Sportler beobachtet und beschrieben haben, der durch Bewegungsmangel die Aufmerksamkeit auf sich gezogen hat. Kurz zuvor ist eben diesem Kommentator das Wort »pomadig« in einem andren Kontext über den Weg gelaufen, und er hielt es nun für passend und vermutlich auch witzig, den lahmen Sportler mit diesem Adjektiv zu bezeichnen. Möglicherweise bezog er sich auch nicht auf einen einzelnen Sportler, sondern auf eine ganze Mannschaft oder auf ein ganzes Turnier. Ich kenne das der Frage zugrundeliegende Zitat nicht.

Dass, wie ich der Frage entnehme, dieses Wort offenbar ausgerechnet im Fall des Fußballs in die Sportberichterstattung eingeführt worden ist, ist reiner Zufall. Es hätte auch Sackhüpfen oder Biathlon sein können.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Du hattest recht, nun nicht mehr. Ich habe meiner Antwort nun nämlich den zuvor fehlenden Fußball-Bezug angefügt.

Comment: Na beim Biathlon haben die doch all Mützen auf, Mensch! ;) Aber pomadig Sackhüpfen... olympisch! Jetzt! :D

Comment: Pomadig ist fester Bestandteil der Fußballberichterstattung. Dass es dem Reporter kurz zuvor in einem anderen Zusammenhang über den Weg lief, ist extrem unwahrscheinlich. Dennoch +1, wg. blasiert, dass es m. E. sehr gut trifft.

Comment: Schöne Herleitung, aber DWDS und Tofros Antwort bieten eine bessere. Anscheinend haben wir es mit einem Adjektiv zu tun, das in zwei Verschiedenen Bedeutungen ins Deutsche gelangt ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Fein, dann kann ich meinen ursprünglichen Kommentar ja wieder löschen. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Vermutung auf schmalem Grat, aber plausibel:

Das Wort hat mit *Pomade* genau nichts zu tun, sondern stammt als Eindeutschung vom polnischen "pomalu" ab, was "langsam" heißt (Im Russischen, Tschechischen und Sorbischen gibt es ähnliche Wortstämme mit ähnlicher Bedeutung).

Der Eindeutschungsprozess hat wohl nach etwas gesucht, worunter man sich auch was vorstellen konnte, und sich an "Pomade" angeglichen.

EDIT: Und siehan, DWDS.de gibt mir recht http://www.dwds.de/?qu=pomadig .

Schaut man sich ngrams an

[image]

Findet man den Gebrauch des Wortes übrigens auch *vor* der allgemeinen Verbreitung von Fussball in Deutschland. Und ich finde auch Suchergebnisse für Volleyball, Basketball und sogar Eishockey, die durchaus im selben Verhältnis wie die Berichte über Fussball, die eben viel häufiger sind, auftreten (Siehe auch Kommentar von Matthias oben). Ich finde aber tatsächlich *sehr wenig*, was nicht mit Ballspielen oder Haaren zu tun hat - Ausser einer Fundstelle im "Kater Murr" von E.T.A Hoffmann.

Und: Es mag Zufall sein, aber Marcel Reif ist auch in Polen geboren.

Comment: Hach, mit Quelle kriegst von mir +1 ;)

Comment: Das bedeutet die eigentliche Frage (nach dem Zusammenhang mit Fußball) zwar bestenfalls unvollständig, aber "this answer is useful" (nämlich für meinen Erkenntniszuwachs) gilt trotzdem: +1

Comment: In meinem obigen Kommentar: "bedeutet" -> "beantwortet" (kopfschüttel...)

Comment: @Jan: Klarer Fall von blindes Huhn - Das Wort ist eine von < 10 polnischen Vokabeln, die ich zufällig kenne...

Answer (score 0):

Mir als Muttersprachler ist *pomadig* ausschließlich in den ersten beiden vom Duden angegebenen Bedeutungen bekannt. Neben der wörtlichen Bedeutung würde ich es irgendwo zwischen *aufgetakelt* und *überheblich* ansiedeln, aber in einem altmodischen Sinn, wo die Überheblichkeit in erster Linie aus sozialem Dünkel besteht und die Mode nicht zeitgemäß ist, sondern eher barocken Stil hat.

Dass sich daraus eine Vorstellung von Schwerfälligkeit entwickelt hat, ist in der Tat naheliegend, aber mir ist das noch nie so begegnet. In meiner Vorstellung dominiert das soziale Verhalten als Kern des Begriffs. Wahrscheinlich kann man einen breiteren Gebrauch im Sinn der Trägheit (noch) als Fußballfachsprache betrachten. Ich verfolge keine Sportberichterstattung, aber viele fußballspezifische Ausdrücke – oft englischen Ursprungs – sind im Lauf der Zeit in die Allgemeinsprache eingedrungen.